# How to write this SQL query to find each account balance?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a transaction table (shown in picture)

https://i.ibb.co/7pdYxxm/hhhhhh.jpg

There's the transaction type (debit/credit)
I need a SQL query that calculates the balance of each account (sum of credits - sum of debts) 
So we group by account_id ... but how can we sum the credits alone and the debits alone?

I am on PostgreSQL! Thank you!

Comment: The image you posted only shows "credit" transactions, i.e. no debits. So is the transaction amount for a debit stored in the database as a positive or a negative number?

Comment: @Abra debits are in positive values too.. they 're not shown in these first rows ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the amount must be substracted when the type = 'C'.

```
    select account_id, sum((case when transaction_type = 'C' then -1 else 1 end) * transaction_amount)
    from trans
    group by account_id
```

base on the transaction type the amount is multiplied by 1 or -1.

Comment: it works as a charm, i only had to switch between 1 and -1. Because in bank accounting, a credit transaction is a positive value on the account of the client!  thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy method to for you to achieve this:

```
select account_id, sum((case when transaction_type = 'C' then 1 else 0 end)*transaction_amount) as sum_of_credit,sum((case when transaction_type = 'D'then 1 else 0 end) * transaction_amount) as sum_of_debit from YourTableNameHere group by account_id;
```

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QD4Oq.png) 
[Sample Output for the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTQd7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 Select sum(Transaction_Amount), 
       Account_Id, 
       Transaction_Type

    From Table_Name
    Group By
       Account_Id,
       Transaction_Type
```